# Package Name - Java EE Web Application

Tags: java, naming-conventions

I'm a beginner in programming web apps with Java EE. How do you name your packages?

I often saw stuff like com.abc.commons...  is there a standard or a common way to do that?

---

Thanks to seanizer, I gonna use your approach: `com.mycompany.myproject.api`

Comment: I removed the `jee6` tag as the question is not specific to a Java SDK or version, and added `naming-conventions` instead.

Comment: that's nice of you, but instead of editing your original post, good stackoverflow practice is to mark the answer as accepted

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These parts usually enter into my package names

1. Domain name (your's or your company's / customer's) backwards
2. Project name
3. Artifact name (api, client, test etc.)
4. Functionality

example:

```
com.mycompany.myproject.api.services
// contains service interfaces for project myproject

com.mycompany.myproject.common.util.string 
// contains string-related utility classes that reside in a library module
// that will be used by several other artifacts
```

One good practice is to have a common root package that is distinct for an individual project (jar etc). For example: in the jar myproject-api.jar , the root package would be `com.mycompany.myproject.api`. That way you always know where to find your classes.

Comment: what do you think about using just the project name alone(that is unique) (like `myproject.api.services`) instead of `com.mycompany.myproject.api.services`. I am liking this more since this is more readable & I think, it actually doesn't make sense to include in every package name the company name /domain etc.. What do you think about this ? Are there any technical issues behind this ? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Marcos no, there are no technical issues that I know of, it's just considered as good practice to have a common package namespace for a company or organization. It makes it easier to group what belongs together

Answer (score 2):

Yes, see the [Sun Naming Conventions](http://java.sun.com/docs/codeconv/html/CodeConventions.doc8.html).

> The prefix of a unique package name is always written in all-lowercase ASCII letters and should be one of the top-level domain names, currently com, edu, gov, mil, net, org, or one of the English two-letter codes identifying countries as specified in ISO Standard 3166, 1981.
>
> Subsequent components of the package name vary according to an organization's own internal naming conventions. Such conventions might specify that certain directory name components be division, department, project, machine, or login names.
>
> Examples:
>
> - com.sun.eng
> - com.apple.quicktime.v2
> - edu.cmu.cs.bovik.cheese

Answer (score 0):

The customary way is to do your own domain backwards, as this is a pretty good guarantee that others do not accidentially use those package names.